# Explicit form of maximal orders of finite representation type

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Hi everybody!

Let $R=k[[u,v]]$ be a power series ring over algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. It is known the complete description of maximal orders over $R$ of finite representation type. (see, for example, M. Artin, “Maximal orders of global dimension and Krull dimension
two”, Invent. Math. 84 (1986), 195–222) According to this description such maximal orders are determined by their ramification data and have been constructed as the ring of invariants $\text{Matr}_{2\times 2}(R)^G$ of certain finite subgroup of $GL_2$.

I'm interested in explicit examples of maximal orders over $R$ of infinite representation type. In particular, the Artin's list of possible ramification curves has not include (for example) curves $\text{E}_8: v^3=u^5$ and $u^4=v^4$ (this one by obvious reasons), so the maximal orders, which ramify over these curves, are evidently of infinite representation type. But I have no explicit form of these orders, i.e. no presentation by generators and relations and it is quite unobvious how to construct them.

Does anyone know such explicit examples or any suitable references?

Comment: Try "Two-dimensional tame and maximal orders of finite representation type" by Reiten and Van den Bergh.  http://books.google.com/books/p/ams?id=-gkC8TgsHrIC&vq=example&source=gbs_navlinks_s 